# react native 0.60.3 with xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, react-native

i have Xcode 9.4 installed and i have a react-native project 0.60.3 and i get an error when i run `react-native run-ios`

```
info In file included from /Users/gonglehan/Desktop/WonderWorld/ProjectN/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.m:8:
/Users/gonglehan/Desktop/WonderWorld/ProjectN/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.h:10:9: fatal error: 'UIKit/UIUserActivity.h' file not found
#import <UIKit/UIUserActivity.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

info

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening ProjectN.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

i see guys that solved the problem by upgrading Xcode to 10 so i wanna know please if 9.4 Xcode version still supported yet ? and how to solve this issue ... 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this issue by upgrading your Xcode.
XCode version should be 10.0+.

[Note]

Error code 65 is related with the Xcode version.